# get offset of each DOM element efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In order to determine the page margin in various positions on the page I need to get the offset, width and height of each DOM element.

I loop over the DOM elements recursively and save each element's attributes.
I tried it with JQuery `$(el).offset()` but it was very slow. I guess that creating a JQuery object for each element by using the`$(...)` is very slow.

Then, I tried an old implementation that I got from an old code which uses native JS and it was X4 times faster.

SO what I'm really asking, is there a different method to accomplish that?
I should mention that my script runs on publishers' sites and I don't really know anything about the page that I'm running on.

Comment: plain vanilla js and a reasonable algorithm should do. maybe you should cache some offsets, depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that, just want to make sure that I'm not missing any trick or something better/sorter/more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one solution, using `map()` and `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');

elements.map(function(val, i, arr) {

  var doc = document.getBoundingClientRect(),
      el = val.getBoundingClientRect(),
      coordsX = el.left - doc.left,
      coordsY = el.top - doc.top;

  return {x: coordsX, y: coordsY};
});
```

This will return an array of all the coordinates of a given class. You can change `document.getElementsByClassName` to `querySelector` if it better suits your needs.

This will also change `getBoundingClientRect()` to be relative to the document instead of the viewport.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect is relative to the viewport, I need it to be relative to the document. And I need to loop over document.body.

Comment: @mrgoos Updated answer.

Comment: You have some issues there. 1st, document.getBoundingClientRect() is not a function. 2nd, map works for arrays only not array-like. But I see where you're going. I'm not sure that it will be better but I will check and update here, Cheers.

Comment: In addition I need a deep loop.